# Объявление переменной в интерфейсе

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь решить некую задачку, а конкретно объявления переменной в интерфейсе(просто хочу разобраться).

На просторах интернета набрёл на способ связанный с расширениям его, попробовав перенести к себе в проект, получилось что то следующее:

```
interface ApiInterface {

object Prop {
        operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): String = "message"
    }
 @Multipart
    @POST(API_FEEDBACK_PATH)
    fun postFeedback(@Part(prop) message: RequestBody,
                     @PartMap files: HashMap<String, RequestBody>,
                     @Part database: MultipartBody.Part?): Call<FeedbackResponse>
}

val ApiInterface.prop: String by ApiInterface.Prop
```

Но увы, в методе postFeedback такое объявление переменной prop не работает. Возможно есть какие то другие способы, так как создание самого объекта для меня также сомнительно.

Answer (score 2):

Переменные декларированные в интерфейсе, всегда статические. Как говорит документация:

> Interface variables are static because Java interfaces cannot be instantiated in their own right; the value of the variable must be assigned in a static context in which no instance exists. The final modifier ensures the value assigned to the interface variable is a true constant that cannot be re-assigned by program code.

Я думаю, что ваша проблема связана именно с этим. Kotlin все равно лишь надстройка над Java.

Comment: Не просто статические, но и final, т.е. уже не переменные, а константы.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно чего пытаетесь добиться, как уже написали в первом ответе, в Java в интерфейсах допускаются только статические константы.

Но Kotlin разрешает объявлять proprties в интерфейсе на раз два.

```
interface MyInterface {
  val prop: Int // abstract

  val propertyWithImplementation: String
    get() = "foo"
}
class Child : MyInterface {
  override val prop: Int = 29
}
```

Офф. документация: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html

Properties доступны через объект, имплементирующий этот интерфейс!

```
val child = Child()
val propValue = child.prop
```